# How can I use k-fold with flow_from_directory and 2 ImageDataGenerators?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, k-fold

I am trying to make a Convolutional Neural Network that detects whether the eye of the user (captured via the computer's webcam live video) is opened or closed.
I used the MRL Eye Dataset of 84898 images (link: http://mrl.cs.vsb.cz/eyedataset), and I split the images into 2 folders: Open_Eyes_Pics and Closed_Eyes_Pics 
I wish to use K-fold but I'm not really knowing how considering this isn't a csv file with labels (X and y)
My Directories:

```
try:
os.mkdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/NN_Eye_Gaze/Open-v-Closed")
os.mkdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/NN_Eye_Gaze/Open-v-Closed/training")
os.mkdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/NN_Eye_Gaze/Open-v-Closed/testing")
os.mkdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/NN_Eye_Gaze/Open-v-Closed/training/Open_Eyes_Pics")
os.mkdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/NN_Eye_Gaze/Open-v-Closed/training/Closed_Eyes_Pics")
os.mkdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/NN_Eye_Gaze/Open-v-Closed/testing/Open_Eyes_Pics")
os.mkdir("C:/Users/User/Desktop/NN_Eye_Gaze/Open-v-Closed/testing/Closed_Eyes_Pics")
except OSError:
    pass
```

Please note that I already created a function to create 2 folders: training and testing, each containing the sub-folders Open_Eyes_Pics and Closed_Eyes_Pics whose names are the labels of the images in each of them.

My generators:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.,
                               horizontal_flip=True,
                               rotation_range=60,
                               brightness_range=[0.5,1.5],
                               width_shift_range=0.2,
                               height_shift_range=0.2,
                               shear_range=0.2,
                               zoom_range=[0.5,1.5]))
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255.)
```

```
train_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
                                              batch_size=1,
                                              class_mode='binary',
                                              color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                              shuffle=True,
                                              target_size=(140, 140)
                                              #subset="training"
                                             )

validation_dataset = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(VALIDATION_DIR,
                                                            batch_size=32,
                                                            class_mode ='binary',
                                                            color_mode = 'grayscale',
                                                            shuffle=True,
                                                            target_size = (140, 140)
                                                            #subset="validation"
                                                           )

# Show what are the labels, and what each label means
train_dataset.class_indices
```

My model:

```
 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
     # Layer 1
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(140, 140, 1),
     padding='Same'),
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(140, 140, 1),
     padding='Same'),
     BatchNormalization(),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     # Layer 2
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='Same'),
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='Same'),
     BatchNormalization(),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     # Layer 3
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='Same'),
     tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='Same'),
     BatchNormalization(),
     tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
     # Layer 4
     #tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='Same'),
     #tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     # Layer 5
     #tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256,(3,3), activation = 'relu'),
     #tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
     # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
     tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
     # 256 neuron hidden layer
     tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
     # 1 output neuron. It will contain either 0 or 1 where 0 is ('ClosedEyes') and 1 for the other ('OpenEyes')
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
print(model.summary())
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
# Train the Model
history = model.fit_generator(train_dataset[train],
                    steps_per_epoch= train_dataset.samples // 32,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_data=validation_dataset [test],
                    validation_steps = validation_dataset.samples // 32,
                    epochs=5,
                    callbacks=[callbacks])
```

Please note that I am still somewhat new to Tensorflow and Convolutional Neural Networks, and essentially my issue began because my validation accuracy is fluctuating.

Comment: Take a look https://medium.com/the-owl/k-fold-cross-validation-in-keras-3ec4a3a00538. Thanks